# how get href attribute in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How i can get href attribute on JQuery on `on` click event
Something like this:

```
$('.nav_step ul li').on('click', function(event){
    this.$('.nav_step ul li a').href;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
$('.nav_step ul li').on('click', function(event){
alert($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.nav_step ul li').on('click', function(event){
    console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```